# How to change the value of a variable in a view?

Tags: python, django

My queryset is currently the value of `posts` in my view. However I want to change my queryset to `Post.objects.all().filter(category=category).order_by('-date')` when the user navigates to the `new` url. Here's my code:

urls

```
url(r'^$', boxes_view, name='home'),
url(r'^new/$', boxes_view, name='new'),
```

views

```
def boxes_view(request):
   ...
   posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=category).annotate(score_diff=F('score__upvotes') - F('score__downvotes')).order_by('-score_diff')
```

template

```
...
<button id="sort_new"><a href="{% url 'new' %}">New</a></button>
```

Is it possible to change the value of `posts` when going through the `new` URL?

Comment: This makes no sense. You can't have two identical URLs.

Comment: My mistake, fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do. But you could pass a parameter from the urls.py to the view:

```
url(r'^$', boxes_view, {'order': '-score_diff'}, name='home'),
url(r'^new/$', boxes_view, {'order': '-date'}, name='new'),

def boxes_view(request, order):
    ...
    posts = Post.objects.all()...order_by(order)
```

Comment: This seems the right method to use, but I tried it and my `new` url is returning an empty queryset. Any idea why? I used a for loop on `posts` and it returns nothing in /new/